# Android - How to use methods from another Java project

Tags: java, android, build

I'm developing an Android app, which is based on classes from a previous Java program. But whenever I try to call a method from the Java project, I get the error on the Android emulator: "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped."

An example:

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), User.dummyString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

causes this error, where the User class is defined like so:

```
public class User {

    public static String dummyString(){
        return "Hello hello";
    }

}
```

I have the Java Project added to the build path of the Android Project, and I have ticked the src folder in the Order and Export tab in the Build Path of the Java Project. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Could you print out your Logcat of the actual stacktrace of the error?  "Unfortunately, MyApp has stopped." is an end user message.

Comment: Ah found it! Logcat was throwing up stuff all over the place so I must have missed it before. This seems to be the relevant one:

_java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.GC01.Coursework.User_

Still not clear on why it can't find the class definition though...

Comment: I posted an answer below. Remember, Logcat is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

So first off, it seems like you are instantiating your User class wrong.

Instead of using.

```
User.dummyString();
```

You should instantiate it like this..

```
 User user = new User();
```

And then try using your method with it.

Also it would help if you posted the error you are getting.

Comment: I think he is doing ok as dummyString() method is static,So is there anything wrong in using User.dummyString();

Comment: dummyString() is a static method, so he should need to instantiate user

Comment: It's a static method, which is why I used the name of the class directly without creating an instance. I did try it with instantiating a `new User();` anyway, but it gave the same error. It won't tell me what the error is with a try-catch, it just shows me [this](http://imgur.com/u3vvM) and then closes the app.

Answer (score 0):

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.GC01.Coursework.User` means that android can't find your `User` class. You're linking the library, but the apk isn't packaging it. You probably need to check your build process again, though the easiest fix would be to just include the source directly in your project.

Comment: When you say I should include the source directly in my project, do you mean copy the folder containing the relevant code? I'd rather not do that, since I'm developing the Java project in parallel, and don't want to have to make all the changes twice. What sort of things should I be checking in my build process?

Comment: If you are developing with source control it isn't a challenge to keep the code up to date. (git: http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=528 , svn: http://subclipse.tigris.org/ ) But if you insist on keeping a single copy of the code then the official android reference works for me: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Comment: I realize that my latter solution only works for android libraries, and your other source that you are trying to link to is not. For non-android libraries, Dalvik needs a compiled jar of the files in its lib folder or it will not be added to the project (even if you list the location of the source in your build path). See this previously accepted solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2539055/902730

Comment: Compiling a jar and relinking it to the android project every time you change that other source would be twice as bothersome as just pushing/pulling your edits from git. I'd go with source control.